# Simplify Swagger authentication with automated JWT request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

We have an API that accepts a Bearer token for many of our calls. We've set up Swagger with the "Authorize" button to accept that token, which works fine.

However, getting that Bearer token is a bit unwieldy for some of our users. They have to use Postman, etc, to pass their username/password and retrieve the token. Then they can plug that token into Swagger.

We would like to streamline and simplify that flow.

Ideally, we would have both username and password fields on the Swagger UI and be able to click Authenticate, which would then retrieve the JWT token from the API, parse the token from the response, and automatically apply the token to all future calls during that Swagger session.

Is such a thing possible in Swagger?

Comment: Which version of swagger are you using?

Comment: This is currently not supported out-of-the-box. See this Swagger UI feature request: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5441